# Shifting left and right text in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I want that in my latex the equation part be on left side of the text which is good (but with some error) but when i want some of my text in right (like commenting on the left text part) it goes down and also if the right text part is more it goes to new line whereas i need it just below the text of right part.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{flushleft}
    N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j}
    \end{flushleft}\begin{flushright}
     used dummy variable concept
    \end{flushright}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be possible to move this question to [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Olivier no :( I think it is not possible to migrate questions that are older than 60 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text comment is short, than the following may be enough:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j}
  \hspace{15mm}
  \text{used dummy variable concept}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Otherwise, I would suggest you to use the `multicols` environment from the [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{equation*}
  N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j}
\end{equation*}
\columnbreak

used dummy variable concept used dummy variable concept used dummy variable concept 
used dummy variable concept used dummy variable concept used dummy variable concept 
used dummy variable concept used dummy variable concept used dummy variable concept 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

giving this result:

[image: two-column output]

You will need to use `\columnbreak` manually (also be careful to the empty lines or not, before and after it) but this works how it is meant to be. Outside the `multicols` environment(s), your body of text is on one column as set by default in the `documentclass`.